# How to get output from MSI Installer, when called from Process

Tags: wix

I have an application in which I am calling a WIX MSI installer using `System.Diagnostic.Process`, on certain button click.

I am passing a parameter to the MSI installer using command line.

Now that same parameter's value can be updated by end user, using a UIDialog available in Wix MSI Installer.

From my calling code, how can I get that updated value, once installer is completed?

Comment: Alternatively, you could ask for it in advance from the application UI and pass it as a property to the MSI. See `msiexec -?`

Comment: Thanks Tom. However how do I get the updated value of parameter back into calling code.

Comment: The idea would be to ask in the launching application, pass property values to the MSIs. running them in a quiet or hidden mode. But, now that you say the data includes a password, that's  not such a good idea because it'll be logged in plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it to the registry during the install and then read it from the registry location in your calling process. This way you can also load the value used when running an upgrade or uninstall of that installer. See the Remember me blog post [here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/) which illustrates how to save the value to the registry and read it in the installer.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Sutherland, However for me this parameter is a database connection string which includes sensitive information like password, hence we cannot use registry here. Do you recommend any other alternative?

Comment: You should be able to encode it before writing it to the registry. Write the encoded value to the registry and decode it when you need the connections string. We do that in our product for a db connection information string. Write an encoded version of it to the registry then read it and decode it when we need to connect to the database.

Comment: If the goal is to hide information that some programs use from other programs that run under the user's account, the data protection API ([DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741(v=vs.110).aspx)) can make them work a lot harder.